# Encrypted notifications under accounts for sandbox mode

Tags: encryption, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using developer mode of paypal to link my developer account while testing my site.
What I notice is that Notification for payment received/refund is encrypted which was not the case before. I want to see the details in english so that I can proceed with my development but this encryption is strucking me at a place.
Do anyone has a solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, the sandbox notification that is showing in Developer.paypal.com portal facing some issue and they're currently fixing it as we speak.

The only workaround that they have provided for us to view the content of the notification, is by clicking the search button in the notification section and then choose the sandbox account that you would like to see, next choose the date range and click the search button.

Now the list should show the same notification list but this time you will be able to see the content.

Attached are the screenshot of the section where you can search. [Click Here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Dxx.png)

Comment: ya, I noticed the same.Thanks for the info

Comment: No Problem.. :)